# Why does Go sha256 give different result than Ubuntu command sha256sum?

Tags: ubuntu, go, sha256, digest

Golang playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/7mHkClUviv) given in a SO question uses the sha256 lib of Go gives a different result than running the following command in Ubuntu linux.

`echo "sha1 this string" | sha256sum`

Go's result: `fceab3bb749b11a43b89f21ccd28e3f5d8b38d5b23eeea960fc169ab482ee2cd`

Linux result: `62d44fd0392ed998179bfd4a162141d7000d1f9aa4fae26465e2e4f57d3a420e`

Is this not the correct way to create a digest in Go? Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Sorry to early viewers, forgot to change the playground link to use sha256 instead of sha1. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because echo appends a `\n` character. Try doing `echo -n`:

```
echo -n "sha1 this string" | gsha256sum
fceab3bb749b11a43b89f21ccd28e3f5d8b38d5b23eeea960fc169ab482ee2cd  -
```

Comment: Aw crap, I specifically used echo because using stdin required a newline before I could hit ctrl+d. Thanks.

Comment: You can hit Ctrl-D twice.